# Loading button (two arrows which rotate) with transition

Tags: html, css

I want to create something like a this loading button after question. It will be nice to get this rotating button for loading anything with pure CSS (not counting the fact that it will be spinning in a click, it will be done with JS). Maybe someone did something like that? Or at least have an idea how to do it. I just know that this is probably possible with `transition`.

**UPD**. No images and icons. My question is about, how to create this kind of borders (two arrows), and rotate them on click (can be done with JS).

Here is example of this button:

[image: Loading button]

Comment: Can you show your attempt on resolving your issue? Any HTML, CSS to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using FontAwesome and the built-in CSS3 rotation

***[jsBin demo](https://jsbin.com/geyiho/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

```css
i.fa-refresh{ color: #a05; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-2x"></i>
```

https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/
https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

---

## Loading Icon (Using plain CSS and CSS3 `animation`)

[image]

```css
.loading{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:  24px;
  height: 24px;
  border:2px solid transparent;
  border-top-color:#a05;
  border-bottom-color:#a05;
  border-radius:50%;
  animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
}
.loading:after,
.loading:before{
  position:absolute;
  content: "";
  width:0; height:0;
  border:6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color:#a05;
}
.loading:after{
  top:1px;
  right:-7px;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.loading:before{
  top:11px;
  left:-7px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
@keyframes rotate{
   to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<span class="loading"></span>
```

Using it with jQuery would end in something like:
***[jsBin demo](https://jsbin.com/savaqi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Comment: yes, but what about to don't use any images and icons? just pure css

Comment: @AleshaOleg those are scalable vector graphics - Fonts.

Comment: so, it will be better to create my own font? Am I right? Because it's too heavy connect whole bootstrap just for one icon:)

Comment: @AleshaOleg that's not bootstrap. (See the file? font-awesome.min.css) It's just FontAwesome. You can use only one icon if you want. Go to font squirrel and download-for-use only the one character/icon you need.

Comment: opps) inattentively read) ok, understood you. Thanks!

Comment: @AleshaOleg I mean you can create that sign using purely CSS, give me a minute I'll show you

Comment: look at this: jsfiddle.net/haoa2f6q

Comment: @AleshaOleg see what I created.

Comment: nice one! How to make it to rotate just on mouse click? Just with jQuery? It should be rotated once (on 360 degree).

Comment: @AleshaOleg yes. Create a class in CSS like `.rotate` and put there the `animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;`. Than using jQuery, on click `$("yourselector").addClass(".rotate")` or `$("yourselector").removeClass(".rotate")` or `$("yourselector").toggleClass(".rotate")`

Comment: can you do it, for full finished answer?

Comment: @AleshaOleg added a demo example at the end of my answer.

Comment: I mean if you click on this button, it takes round - then stop. Then again click on it, and again stop.

Comment: @AleshaOleg ok... so? What's the problem with it? You can stop it whenever you want. Have you seen at all - the jQuery code?

Comment: nothing:) I just mean this one: jsfiddle.net/w5bdjdd3/1. Can you change your jQuery code for this, for completed answer?

Comment: @AleshaOleg you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Check out codepen (fair point out: not my codepen) here for some idea of how to create a css only arrow kinda like what you're thinking about: 
    http://codepen.io/artemdemo/pen/fLcCn/
the circling is not possible with transition effect but its possible with css only assuming you have the rotating icon already, just make a hover animation like:

```
.rotate{
    animation: rotate ease infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate{
   to{ transform: rotate(360deg); }
   from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

and then on click add the class rotate to the element

Comment: yes, i know about rotating. I thinks my question more about how to make this kind of borders (two arrows).

Comment: check this one: jsfiddle.net/haoa2f6q. How to rotate it for example on hover? With transition? But anyway it will be easy to make it rotate with transition:)

Comment: @AleshaOleg here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/haoa2f6q/2/

Comment: @AleshaOleg and an example of onclick instead: http://jsfiddle.net/haoa2f6q/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cursor URL property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property) and link it to an animated GIF of your spinner.

```
/* CSS */
.wait { cursor: url(wait.gif), wait; }

/* JavaScript */
if (waiting)
    document.body.classList.add('wait');
```

Comment: I think it will be better make it with svg

Comment: Good idea.  SVGs are better.